# How to set up Unreal camera dimensions to export a book cover?

Tags: rendering, camera, unreal-4, image, export

In the following image, you can see the camera settings of Unreal Engine.

[image: Unreal camera settings]

Suppose you have a scene. How can I setup the camera dimensions to match perfectly, and ready to export, an Amazon ebook cover; and a book front cover, back cover and spine?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your book? What are the dimensions of an Amazon ebook cover?

Comment: @DMGregory 2,560 pixels in height x 1,600 pixels in width.

Comment: I mean, I can of course substitute the values, but will not occur any sorts of deformations on camera lens?